# ASP.net Login Page C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I created a simple web application that consists of several webforms. The initial startup page is Login.aspx and it has several controls (textboxes for username and password and buttons to login and exit). Currently I just check for a specific strings for user name and password . If the comparison is successful then the application will redirect the flow to the main menu. My problem is that I can change the name of the webform in the links and I can bypass the login page. I would like some ideas to how to do this so I can prevent the user from navigating from the link url. Side Note: This web application is not critical at this stage so I am not looking for very complicated methods. I just want to prevent the user from navigating their way from the url.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that other views (sites) are accessibl only by authorized users (logged). In case you are using ASP.Net MVC take a look at `[Authorize]` attribute by which you can restrain access only to authorized users. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't develop the application using the MVC approach. I just created an ASP empty web application and added a few empty web application and designed them from scratch. Everything works the way I want it and even the login works perfectly except that users can navigate from one web form to another (if they know the name of the web form) by adding the name before (.aspx). I didn't publish the application on any web server yet. It runs from my localhost machine but I noticed this behavior and I was wondering how to prevent it. Any Ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: you can not authorize your pages only by adding a login page.. clearify how and which pages you authorize. do you check if request is authorized in the requested page(webform) or do you configure web.config

Comment: I am not doing any authorization. Also, the way I started building this application is not with MVC. It is just empty web application and then I started adding web forms. In my code i am just checking for a specific user name and password and based on that it redirects to the main menu. I am not familiar with the authorization method you are referring to. Does prevent the user from playing with the url to change the name of the web from?

Comment: it is obvious that you are not doing authorization but you should! you can play with the url however you want if your web forms are "protected" by being accessible only by authorized users - the users you are checking for specific names. Just take a look at this article, it;s pretty simple and also for ASP web forms...you should be able to achieve your goal by that.